# AWS lambda using incorrect host name

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to connect to my postgres RDS using AWS lambda. This is what my code looks like -

```
#rds settings

import psycopg2
hostname  = "10.126.152.143"
username = "user"
password = "password"
database = "sandbox"

# Simple routine to run a query on a database and print the results:
def doQuery( conn ) :
    try:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute( "select status from employee" )
        print("Done")
    except:
        print("Something went wrong")

def handler(event, context):
    myConnection = psycopg2.connect(host=hostname, port=5432, user=username, password=password, database=database )
    doQuery( myConnection )
    myConnection.close()
    return "Done"
```

I was able to get the package installed and running. I am uing this command to ivnoke the lambda.

```
aws lambda invoke --function-name lambda output.txt
```

I get the error `FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry`. Howere the host is diffrent everytime I try to invoke the lambda.

Output of 1st run of lambda

```
{"errorMessage": "FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host \"10.126.152.243\", user \"user\", database \"sandbox\", SSL off\n", "errorType": "OperationalError", "stackTrace": [["/var/task/app.py", 27, "handler", "myConnection = psycopg2.connect( host=hostname, port=5432, user=username, password=password, database=database )"], ["/var/task/psycopg2/__init__.py", 130, "connect",
```

Output of 2nd run of lambda

```
{"errorMessage": "FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host \"10.126.153.13\", user \"user\", database \"sandbox\", SSL off\n", "errorType": "OperationalError", "stackTrace": [["/var/task/app.py", 27, "handler", "myConnection = psycopg2.connect( host=hostname, port=5432, user=username, password=password, database=database )"], ["/var/task/psycopg2/__init__.py", 130, "connect", "conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)"]]}
```

I have the same VPC and security groups for the lambda, as the RDS, so I don't think connectivity should be an issue.

I am not sure why the host is different every time I invoke the lambda ? And why is it not the one that I specified

Comment: `pg_hba.conf` is a security configuration file for PostgreSQL databases. It is additional to Security Group settings. AWS Lambda functions can use multiple Elastic Network Interfaces, hence the changing IP address. Take a look at the PostgreSQL documentation to learn how to add an entry to allow access from certain IP addresses. Use the full CIDR range of the VPC to allow any resource in the VPC to access it.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein or better yet, use the security group ID assigned to the Lambda function, instead of opening up the full CIDR range of the VPC.

Comment: "I have the same VPC and security groups for the lambda, as the RDS" Having the same security group assigned to multiple things is meaningless, that alone does not allow those two things to communicate with each other, and is actually considered a bad practice.

Comment: The fact that the user is receiving a `no pg_hba.conf entry` error indicates that the Security Groups are allowing the connection. The login is being denied by the database itself.

Comment: If you're running in RDS, you have no ability to directly modify `pg_hba.conf`. The only thing that I know of that _does_ modify this file is to set the `rds.force_ssl` parameter. I suspect that this parameter is set, because part of the error message indicates that you're not using SSL to connect.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in my case was that the RDS was configured to force SSL with `rds.force_ssl` being set to 1.

Updating the code to enable SSL fixed the issue.

```
sslrootcert = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'rds-ca-2019-root.pem')
conn = psycopg2.connect(host=hostname, user=username, password=password, database=database, sslmode=sslmode, sslrootcert=sslrootcert)
```

Comment: What is the `sslmode` variable you are passing to psycopg2.connect()?